# Showing the status of a process in Coldfusion using JQuery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Using Coldfusion I am running a loop over a csv file which could take some time, I am not displaying anything on the page really but would like to use a JQuery plugin that shows the status of the loop.

What would be the best way to achieve this and what plugin would be best? UI is not of importance at all

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cfflush I have done the following:

```
<cfflush>

    <cfflush interval=1>
    <!---LOOP THROUGH CSV FILE--->

    <!---SET ROWCOUNT--->
    <cfset loop_currentrow = 1>

    <cfloop index="index" list="#file#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">
            <!---DISPLAY PROGRESS--->
             Completed row #loop_currentrow# of #debitresults.recordcount#<br />
            <!---UPDATE THE ROWCOUNT--->
            <cfset loop_currentrow = #loop_currentrow# + 1>

    </cfloop>
```

Seems to work fine for what I wanted and learnt something new! Thanks @LifeOfBri_!

Answer (score 4):

I can't really tell if you're trying to crowdsource the writing of your site, but err well... I'd probably have it so that, every `x` iterations, it called a function that would write the percentage complete to a key store value, you would then use jQuery to AJAX a request to a function that got the result from that keystore for output.

Comment: no I do a lot of coldfusion dev but I am trying to learn myself the things that I have not done yet but thanks I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

If UI is not of importance, why use Jquery at all?  Can't you just use cfoutput your position in the loop, and then use cfflush in each iteration (or say, every 10th iteration) to push it to the browser before the request is finished?

Comment: Hi @TheLifeOfBri_ I have never heard of cfflush, that acctually sounds pretty cool! I will give it a go! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TheLifeOfBri_ ! I am using cffile to loop <cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">, do you have any idea how I can get the currentrow and to total rows within the loop even if it is not inside of the csv file?

Comment: you know what, I've never used `cfflush` before either.  so if you can do it that way, sounds a lot simpler than my answer